# How to convert binary values within a list of ndarray objects to decimal values?

Tags: python, binary, decimal, data-conversion

My list contains 49 entries. The size of the entries varies. For example, the first entry consists of 3032 rows and 27 columns. This corresponds to 27 signals with 3032 data each. The data is currently in binary. The size of the column also varies within an entry (the 27 columns do not have the same size). For example, the first signal of the first entry has the following format:

```
print(signal_reshape_list[0][:,0] #print first entry, first signal with all columns
```

Output: [list([1, 1]) list([1, 1])  list([1, 1])  list([1, 1])....list([1, 1])  list([1, 1])]

list([1, 1]) corresponds to the binary number 0x00000011 and would therefore be "3" as decimal number representation.

```
print(signal_reshape_list[0][:,0] #print first entry, third signal with all columns
```

Output: [list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([1, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 1]) .... list([0, 1, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0])]

list([0, 0, 1, 0]) corresponds to the binary number 0x00000010 and would therefore be "2" as decimal number representation. list([1, 0, 1, 0]) corresponds to the binary number 0x00001010 and would therefore be "10" as decimal number representation. And so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a list like this:

`Output: [list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([1, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 1]) .... list([0, 1, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0]) list([0, 0, 1, 0])]`

and desire out put is like :`[2,10,3,..,6,2,2]`
it can be down by below code that applied on output:

```
a= [list([0, 0, 1, 0]), list([1, 0, 1, 0]), list([0, 0, 1, 1])]
out=[]
for l in range(0,len(a)):
    A=a[l]
    out.append(A[3]+A[2]*2+A[1]*4+A[0]*8)

print(out)
```

And output:
`out: [2, 10, 3]`

**Update:**

Each list elements should concatenate to get binary string like `0010`then it will change to decimal value by int(result, 2)
here is the code:

```
a= [list([0, 0, 1, 0]), list([1, 0, 1, 0]), list([0, 0, 1, 1,0, 0, 1, 1])]
out=[]
for l in range(len(a)):
    result= ''
    for element in a[l]:
        result += str(element)
    out.append(int(result,2))    

print(out)
```

Binary output:`['0010', '1010', '00110011']`
decimal output:`[2, 10, 51]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this solution will fail as the entries within my lists varies. For example if my list has only three entries: [list([0, 0, 1]) list([1, 0, 1])..] your code doesn't work. It can also happen, that there are almost 35 entries within my list: [list([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0........]) .... ]. For this case it's also not working.

Comment: It would work with up to for element with out problem.Yes your right for the more it would have problem. Now I get your question. let me check

Comment: Another solution would be to get a binary string out of each: [list([0, 0, 1]) list([1, 0, 1]). As binary string we would get '001' and '101'. Working with int('binary_string', 2) i would get my result. Do you know how to create the binary string?

Comment: you can use this to convert you list to binary string:
let me update ansert

 `result= ''
for element in a[0]:
        result += str(element)

print(result)`

Comment: Suggestion: `result = ''.join(str(element) for element in a[l])`

Comment: Suggestion #2: `for l in a:` so you can do `result = ''.join(str(element) for element in l)` next.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I didn't manage to apply your suggestions to my problem. I  posted a new answer with my working code. Maybe you could add your solution as an edit. Thank you!